# bash capture output from remote machine into a variable

Tags: bash, for-loop

I'm trying to capture several remote device's output using the cli command then grep 717GE and print to screen for multiple hosts. As you see below its capturing the IP from $hosts and passing it to $outip, instead of what is shown when you use the same command from the command line.  I thought the variable would capture the data returned from the given command.  Could someone assist me and help me understand what I'm doing wrong?  I'm really interested in learning so please hold off on the snarky comments. If possible.

```
for host in ${hosts[@]}; do
  seven=( $(cli $hosts show gpon ont summary -n --max=3 --host ) )
  outip=( $(grep 717GE $seven) )
  echo $outip
done
```

output:

```
+ for host in '${hosts[@]}'
+ seven=($(cli $hosts show gpon ont summary -n --max=3 --host ))
++ cli 10.100.112.2 show gpon ont summary -n --max=3 --host
+ outip=($(grep 717GE $seven))
++ grep 717GE 10.100.112.2 grep: 10.100.112.2: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Your commands don't seem to make much sense.  Try `VAR=$(ssh user@server "some command here")`

Comment: ssh is not listening on the remote device.  I'm using cli for various reasons. USAGE: cli <target> [<commands>] [c:<command_file>] [options]

Comment: 1. Remove parenthesis around `seven` and `outip`: `seven=$(cli $hosts show gpon ont summary -n --max=3 --host)` `outip=$(grep 717GE $seven)` 2. While setting `seven`, you seem to have a typo: use `$host` instead of `$hosts`.

Comment: Thanks, it actually helped but there are other issues I need to work out.  The formatting is not right. Also this error: grep: unrecognized option `----|----------|-----|------------|-----|------|----------|--------|------------'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.
+ outip=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `var=( .. )` unless you want to create an array, and use a bash here-string `grep something <<< "$var"` (equivalent to `echo "$var" | grep something`) to search for matching lines (otherwise you're saying that `$var` contains a list of filenames to search, and some options to set for `grep`):

```
for host in ${hosts[@]}; do
  # Assign as variable rather than array, and use $host instead of hosts
  seven=$(cli $host show gpon ont summary -n --max=3 --host )
  # Grep with "$seven" as text input and not as a list of filenames
  outip=$(grep 717GE <<< "$seven")
  echo "$outip"
done
```

Comment: You my newly acquired friend, are amazing.  Thanks for the lesson too. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: One more question. My script breaks when there is no 717GE to list.  Is it best to nest an If-else statement in my for statement?

Comment: Nvm.. I had {set -e} at the beginning of the script and when i removed it, my script worked perfectly. THANKS!!